# What will happen when my application swipe( killed) from list of recent applications?

Tags: android, csip-simple

My application is receiving calls(using CsipSimple) it's working fine,

**But my problem is** when i am getting call, On that time, am killing the 
application from list of recent applications.calling notification also killing(Not showing).

What will Happen when swiping the app from recent applications?

1. is there any override method to be invoked?
2. What is the behavior of 'SERVICE' Component?
3. All objects going to be null?

Please guide me, Your help will be appreciated.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried background service?

Comment: yes, am using services

Comment: Have you tried same test case on viber or any other VOIP application?

Comment: removing your app from the recents list completely kills your app that means any services that are running too. there is no override method to stop it

Comment: @Nouman Ghaffar Yes,i was tested 'Whats App' application,it is not happening.

Comment: @tyczj Yes, is there no solution from killing?

Comment: @GangadharNimbally you cannot stop your app from getting killed, that would be a big security problem if you could

Answer (score 0):

When your app is killed by that method, it is force Garbage Collected, so every value that wasn't stored in a Db or in Shared Preferences or some form of storing data would be deleted with no chance of recovery. If you want your app to perhaps restart in the background to do background processes when it is killed, you would need to add a Service that would do minor things like send little data here and there, if you hug too much resources even with a service, Android now does a good job of cutting you off completely. And I heard there could possibly be a feature that sorts of blacklists you.

This tutorial does a good job of explicitly explaining the Service type.
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

try using no. 5 in the Table of Content of the tutorial.

Android gives a guide on what to do and what not to do when using a service with this https://developer.android.com/training/best-background.html

And this is a more specific Tutorial with explicit details on doing downloads from
http://javatechig.com/android/creating-a-background-service-in-android